# Is pushing an object to an array async operation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I was doing one problem-solving program where I had to find all the pairs from an array that adds up to a target (classic two-sum program just with a little addition). This was my first approach:

```
let findPair = (arr, target) => {
    let res = [];
    let mappingArr = new Map()
    let obj = {
        first: 0,
        second: 0
    }

    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        let comp = target - arr[i];
        if(mappingArr.has(comp)){
            obj.first = arr[mappingArr.get(comp)];
            obj.second = arr[i];
            res.push(obj)
        } else {
            mappingArr.set(arr[i], i)
        }
    }
    return res;
}

let arr = [8, 7, 2, 5, 3, 1]
let target = 10;

let sumPair = findPair(arr, target);
console.log(sumPair);
```

**
This should output: [{first: 8, second: 2},{first: 7, second: 3}]
but instead it prints: [{first: 7, second: 3},{first: 7, second: 3}]
**

Now if I make one little change in the for loop like this:

```
if(mappingArr.has(comp)){
    res.push({first: arr[mappingArr.get(comp)], second: arr[i]});
} else {
    mappingArr.set(arr[i], i)
}
```

by directly pushing the object instead of first assigning to one object and then pushing the object to an array, it works fine.

I also faced a similar issue with my back-end code once. That time too I couldn't understand why the issue was arising.

Any idea why this is happening.?

Thanks.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first version, you just have *one* `obj`:

```
let obj = {
    first: 0,
    second: 0
}
```

The loop then *mutates* that *same* object, and pushes it unto the array. This means the array gets multiple references to the *same* object. Even when the object is already pushed to the array, the next iteration mutates that object.

Since there is only *one* such object, it is expected that you see the same output for all entries in the array.

The easiest solution is to define a *new* object in every iteration. So move the above `let` inside the loop, and it will work. But what you did in the second version uses the same principle: you create a new object each time you push it unto the array.

Comment: Wow.! Thank you for the quick reply and precise explanation.! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening because you have declared variable "obj" outside for loop, so it's reference is always same when you modify it in iterations.

Declare it inside loop and that will solve your problem.

```
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
   let obj = {
        first: 0,
        second: 0
    }
        let comp = target - arr[i];
        if(mappingArr.has(comp)){
            obj.first = arr[mappingArr.get(comp)];
            obj.second = arr[i];
            res.push(obj)
        } else {
            mappingArr.set(arr[i], i)
        }
    }
```